# How to hide a device/volume after mounting on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, volume, mount

I wrote a little program, where i mounted an encrypted volume after the user inserts the password with veracrypt an showed the content to the user in a specific way inside my programm. Everything works fine, but i want to prevent that the volume is shown in Nautilus.

The following command mounts the volume:

```
"veracrypt -m ro /path/to/file/file -p" + pw
```

Veracrypt help command shows:

```
 --fs-options=OPTIONS
   Filesystem mount options. The OPTIONS argument is passed to mount(8)
   command with option -o when a filesystem on a VeraCrypt volume is mounted.
   This option is not available on some platforms.
```

But i'm not able to find a mount option for linux-mount command, which will do the job. Is there any? What can i do?

Comment: you're looking for a way to mount the disk in linux ?

Comment: no i can mount it successfully and it also shows up, but i want to mount it "silent?" oder "hidden". So it doesn't show up in the GUI (e.g. Nautilus)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

A simple workaround may be to mount the volume to a directory that begins with a `.`. These directories should not be visible in most file managers without specifying they should show hidden files/folders.

Of course, obscuring the folder isn't perfect and is no substitute for setting proper access control specifies via `chmod`.